# FuelUX - Convert Json string to FuelUX tree data

Tags: javascript, json, fuelux

My WebAPi is returning JSON string as shown below
{"DataProvider":{"AdministrationDatabase":{"ConnectionString":{"@IsEncrypted":"false","#text":"Data Source=***bank.dev\GROUPCHAT;Database=Administration;User Id=devsa;Password=P@ssw0rd!;"}},"ApplicationAdministrationDatabase":{"ConnectionString":{"@IsEncrypted":"false","#text":"Data Source=***bank.dev\CHAT;Database=ApplicationAdministration;User Id=devsa;Password=P@ssw0rd!;"}},"Database":{"ConnectionString":{"@IsEncrypted":"false","#text":"Data Source=***bank.dev\GROUPCHAT;Database=ZLExtract;User Id=devsa;Password=P@ssw0rd!;"}}}}

How I can convert it so the FuelUXTree can accept this as datasource.

Here is manually converted data :

{"DataProvider":{"name":"DataProvider","type":"folder","additionalParameters":{"children":{"AdministrationDatabase":{"name":"AdministrationDatabase","type":"folder","additionalParameters":{"children":{"ConnectionString":{"name":"ConnectionString","type":"folder","additionalParameters":{"children":{"text":{"name":"Data Source=***bank.devGROUPCHAT;Database=Administration;User Id=devsa;Password=P@ssw0rd!;","type":"item"},"IsEncrypted":{"name":"false","type":"item"}}}}}}},"ApplicationAdministrationDatabase":{"name":"ApplicationAdministrationDatabase","type":"folder","additionalParameters":{"children":{"ConnectionString":{"name":"ConnectionString","type":"folder","additionalParameters":{"children":{"text":{"name":"Data Source=***bank.devGROUPCHAT;Database=Administration;User Id=devsa;Password=P@ssw0rd!;","type":"item"},"IsEncrypted":{"name":"false","type":"item"}}}}}}},"ZLExtractDatabase":{"name":"ZLExtractDatabase","type":"folder","additionalParameters":{"children":{"ConnectionString":{"name":"ConnectionString","type":"folder","additionalParameters":{"children":{"text":{"name":"Data Source=***bank.devGROUPCHAT;Database=Administration;User Id=devsa;Password=P@ssw0rd!;","type":"item"},"IsEncrypted":{"name":"false","type":"item"}}}}}}}}}}}

Comment: My data is already in JSON.. I dont need JSON.Parse

Comment: You need to parse the JSON in order for a function to process it.

Comment: I need a function which can transform my existing JSON data to the format that FuelUX tree want like adding extra parameters.

Comment: `data.newproperty = newvalue`?

Comment: BTW, JSON is a string of JS data. It needs to be parsed to a JS object for you to be able to process it. It's only a matter of termininology, but an important one.

Comment: I am not able write logic to format json the way FuelUX expects it. I have pasted both string in my quesion